# How do I bind shift-enter in my .muttrc?

Tags: mutt

I'd like to say `bind index \S<enter> ...` if I knew what `\S` should be and `<enter>` should be.  Where should I have found them in the mutt documentation?  Where's the list of control characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do that, because terminals send the same sequence for both <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, so mutt cannot know the difference.

Comment: Aw, man... This stinks!

Comment: Pity. Browsers can tell the difference.

Comment: @JohnBaber: Your browser does not run inside a terminal. It receives key events directly from the X11 server (or equivalent for Windows/OSX). It is therefore not constrained by the same limitations as the terminal-based Mutt.